# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Filename'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was requiring some data from a .json file but I am getting this error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../Jsons/eshop.json'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Pooyan\Desktop\PDM Bot Main\commands\shop.js:9:24)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Pooyan\Desktop\PDM Bot Main\events\guild\message.js:114:15)
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '../Jsons/eshop.json'
}
```

My code:

```js
let shop_data = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(fs.readFileSync('../Jsons/eshop.json')).toString());
    let index = (args[0] || "1");
    let page = shop_data.pages[index];
```

I think that's all you need, but if any other code was needed, comment it.
I am using discord.js v13 and node.js 16

Comment: readFileSync already return buffer, no need Buffer.from function. FYI

Comment: Don't use absolute paths, it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the path. It seems the path is invalid for the given `eshop.json` file or there might be any spelling mistake in the path.

`fs.readFileSync` takes the relative path:

- test.js
- JSON

  - sampleJSON

    - eshop.json

```
fs.readFileSync('./JSON/sampleJSON/eshop.json');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **path** module and **join the folder** names to define the json file location.

Let,the data is in following directory.   ( ***NewProject/data/eshop.json*** )

- NewProject

  - Project root directory
  - data

    - eshop.json

You want to access the **eshop.json** file from any file under the project directory.

Solution is below:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path');
const directory = path.join('data', 'eshop.json')
// directory ==> data\eshop.json
exports.getRandomUserService = () => {
     const jsonData = fs.readFileSync(directory);
     const eshop= JSON.parse(jsonData);
     console.log('eshop data from json file: ',eshop);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the problem came from module reading path, if your case is fs.readFile is working find until you call it from *root* index.js

If Your Path 
`-index.js` 
`./services/getData.js` (fs.readFile func is calling here) 
`./json/eshop.json`

Inside index.js

```
app.get( '/eshop', getData);
```

Have to change view side of *./services/getData.js* to *index.js*

```
'../json/eshop.json'
```

To

```
'./json/eshop.json'
```

I got the same issue, this fix me, no need to install anything.